# Constructing completion of metric space on closed intervals

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

Given $$X=\{[a,b] | -\infty < a < b < \infty \}$$ and $|I|=b-a$ for $I=[a,b]$, I have already proved that $d: X\times X \to \mathbb{R}$ where $$d(I,J)=|I|+|J|-2|I\cap J|$$
is a metric. I am now asked to construct a completion $(\tilde{X}, \tilde{d})$ of $(X,d)$ but am lost doing so.
I know that $X\subset \tilde{X}$ has to be dense, $\tilde{d}=d$ on $X$ and all cauchy sequences have to converge.

Comment: as a first observation, we need the one-point intervalls $[a,a]$ in the completion.

Comment: Look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space#Completion) for a construction of the completion.

Comment: @jjagmath is there a more direct way of expressing the completed space such that $[a,a]$ or $[a,b)$ being in the completion is more obvious (like flukx noted)?

Comment: The question is not precise. It is a bad question since constructing the completion is the same for all the metric spaces. May be the person who give you the question should specify what was expected after constructing the completion. May be the space has some simple way of describing it, but since the question is not precise, it's hard to tell what are you supposed to answer.

Comment: @stack_math Note that $[a,a]$ cannot be distinguished in the completion from any other zero-length set since $d([a,a], [0,0]) = a - a + 0 - 0 - 2 · 0 = 0$. So it's the same element in the completion of $X$. So my first comment was not really correct.

Comment: @flukx That's only true if the extension of the metric has the same formula for the new points

Answer (score 1):

I think the completion just needs one more element, something of size $0$.

Let $(I_n)_n$ be a sequence in $X$.
First note that the sequence of intervall lengths $(|I_n|)_n$ needs to be a Cauchy sequence:
$$
\begin{align}
\big||I_n| - |I_k|\big| &= \Big| \big(|I_n| - |I_n \cap I_k|\big) - \big(|I_k| - |I_n \cap I_k|\big) \Big| \\ &\leq |I_n| - |I_n \cap I_k| + |I_k| - |I_n \cap I_k| \\ &= d(I_n, I_k)
\end{align}
$$
$(I_n)_n$ is a sequence in $ℝ$ and therefore has a limit.

Case 1: $|I_n|→ 0$ as $n → ∞$. Then $(I_n)_n$ is a Cauchy-Sequence and is equivalent to all other such sequences since $d(I_n, I_k) \leq |I_n| + |I_k| → 0$. Since there is no element in $X$ with size $0$, we should add one. As I commented any does the job, $[1,1]$ is not different to $[0,0]$.

Case 2: $|I_n| → L > 0$. Then drawing pictures leads to he conclusion that the intervalls must agree on a growing portion.
My claim is that
$$
\lim_{n → ∞} I_n := \overline{\bigcup_{k ∈ ℕ} \underbrace{\bigcap_{n \geq k} I_n}_{=: B_k}}
$$
is in $X$ and the limit of the Cauchy sequence $(I_n)_n$.

Let $x_n → x$ be a convergent sequence in $B_k$. Then it is a convergent sequence in all $I_n$ ($n\geq k$) and hence $x ∈ I_n$ for all $n \geq k$, hence $x ∈ B_k$. So $B_k$ is closed. It is an intervall since otherwise there must be an $I_n$ ($n ≥ k$) that has this gap.

Since we are intersecting less and less intervalls while $k → ∞$, the sequence $\left( B_k \right)_k$ is monotonically increasing with respect to $\subset$. Therefore $\bigcup_{k ∈ ℕ} B_k$ is an intervall as well and the closure $\lim_{n→∞} I_n$ is therefore a closed intervall. Since $|I_n|$ converges and is therefore bounded, each of $B_k$ is bounded by the same constant and therefore $\lim_{n→∞} I_n$ is bounded by this constant. Hence $\lim_{n→∞} I_n ∈ X$. (Here bounded means that the size/length/ $|·|$ is bounded.)

Now to $I_n → \lim_{n → ∞} I_n$.
Let $ε > 0$. Take $k$ such that for all $m, p \geq k$ we have $d(I_n, I_m) < ε$. Since $B_k \subset I_p$, $d(I_p, B_k) = |I_p \setminus B_k|$. Let us first look at the part of $I_p$ that is left of $B_k$.
There must be some $m \geq n$ such that the left (lower) end of $I_m$ is arbitrarily ($ε' \geq 0$) close to $\min B_k$. Then $ε > d(I_p, I_m) = |I_p \setminus B_k| - ε' + d(I_p \setminus B_k, I_m \setminus B_k)$ (the last summand is the part right of $B_k$.) Hence $|I_p \setminus B_k| < ε + ε' - d(\text{parts on the right})$. Since $ε'$ was arbitrary, $|I_p \setminus B_k| < ε$.
 <sub>I am somehow suspicious that this argument is fine since I thought I had to do the same thing on the right but somehow I get to my conclusion anyway.</sub>

So $d(I_p, B_k) < ε$ or in other terms $d(I_k, B_k) → 0$ as $k → ∞$.

The last step feels like it shouldn't be too hard but my head is a bit too mushy¹ for that right now.

¹Is that suitable English?